# Перенаправление при заходе на поддомен

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте. Есть правило htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^.[a-z-]+\.site\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/%1
```

вопрос. как сделать чтобы перенаправление было на **site.ru/sub_domain**
где sub_domain - поддомен, который создается динамически sub_domain.site.ru

*.site.ru в панели уже создал

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^([a-z-]+)\.site\.ru$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/%1
```

P.S. Вместо `%{SERVER_NAME}` наверное `%{HTTP_HOST}` нужно использовать.

P.P.S. Если путь тоже нужен, то

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/%1/$1
```